# Windows: establish file association to batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-association

I created a custom file extension I would associate to a batch script.
I used

```
ASSOC .myext=MY.FILETYPE
FTYPE MY.FILETYPE=cmd /c "C:\Path\of\my\batch.bat" %1 %*
```

by now the batch file "C:\Path\of\my\batch.bat" is a simple one-liner

```
echo %1
```

And roughly works: double clicking a .myext file pops up a cmd shell echoing the file path.
But a problem arises when the .myext file is in a path containing spaces: the echoed filepath is truncated to the space.
Double quoting the %1 in the FTYPE statement seems not to work.

```
FTYPE MY.FILETYPE=cmd /c "C:\Path\of\my\batch.bat" "%1" %*
```

Comment: are you calling `FTYPE MY.FILETYPE=cmd /c "C:\Path\of\my\batch.bat" "%1" %*` from bat file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double quoting `%1` is correct, but it fails as cmd.exe contains a bug when the command and at least one parameter contains quotes.
So you need to make the command without quotes by inserting `CALL`.

```
FTYPE MY.FILETYPE=cmd /c call "C:\Path\of\my\batch.bat" "%1" %*
```

Comment: Thanks Jeb! Your solution works but I think it should be without tilde: FTYPE MY.FILETYPE=cmd /c call "C:\Path\of\my\batch.bat" "%1" %*

Comment: @FedericoDestefanis The tilde is for removing quotes from %1, that should be done so that there are always only one pair of quotes after adding them with `"%~1"`. else you can get something like `""C:\with space\xyz""`

Comment: @FedericoDestefanis I'm wrong! In the FTYPE the `%~1` doesn't work like in a batch file, it will not expand.

Answer (score 2):

Change the batch file `"C:\Path\of\my\batch.bat"` content to

```
echo %*
```

Your `ASSOC` and `FTYPE` statements seem to be all right.

**Edit** accordig to *Monacraft*'s comment.

This solution is correct as `%1` will reference the document *filename* while that `%*` will reference to further parameters: *If any further parameters are required by the application they can be passed as* `%2`, `%3`. *To pass **all** parameters to an application use* `%*`.

Handy for using `aFile.myext a b c` right from command line, although for that use the `FTYPE` statement should be

> FTYPE MY.FILETYPE=cmd /D /C "C:\Path\of\my\batch.bat "%1"" %*

to differentiate first parameter if contains spaces.

**Example**: with

```
ASSOC .xxx=XXXFILE
rem a bug here FTYPE XXXFILE=%ComSpec% /D /C "d:\bat\xxxbatch.bat "%1"" %*
rem definitely switched to Jeb's solution as follows
FTYPE XXXFILE=%comspec% /D /C call "d:\bat\xxxbatch.bat" "%1" %*
```

and `xxxbatch.bat` as follows

```
@echo(
@echo %*
@if "%2"=="" pause
@goto :eof
```

**Output**:

```
d:\bat>D:\test\xxxFileNoSpaces.xxx aa bb cc

"D:\test\xxxFileNoSpaces.xxx"  aa bb cc

d:\bat>"D:\test\xxx file with spaces.xxx" dd ee

"D:\test\xxx file with spaces.xxx"  dd ee

d:\bat>
```

Comment: @Monacraft Nope. This solution is correct, see my edit

Comment: At least on Win7 you can't start your `test.xxx`, I get `The syntax of your filename, directory or drive is wrong`. The main problem is the `cmd /c "batch.bat" "%1"`

Comment: @jeb :) read again and thoroughly check: `cmd /c "batch.bat "%1""` instead of wrong `cmd /c "batch.bat" "%1"`. Note position of spaces and `"` quotes. At least on Win8... :)

Comment: You are right, I missed that! But your solution has some disadvantages, it splits parameters at the wrong places. Try `test.xxx "aa bb"`, `"aa` is now part of `%1` and in `%2` is only bb

Comment: @jeb the `cmd.exe` bug [you have mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28189485/3439404) seems to be insurmountable... What did *they* accomplish that? :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using this from a bat file try to change it to:

```
ASSOC .myext=MY.FILETYPE
FTYPE MY.FILETYPE=cmd /c "C:\Path\of\my\batch.bat" "%%1" %%*
```

I think even

```
  FTYPE MY.FILETYPE="C:\Path\of\my\batch.bat" "%%1" %%*
```

should work.