# Python IDLE.bat, not IDLE.exe, installed on Win10 with Python 3.9

Tags: python, default, python-idle

I have just installed 3.9 to replace a 3.6 installation on my laptop.
Because Windows file association only works with .exe files, not .bat, files, there is no way to click on a file .py and get it to open with IDLE.  But it did with 3.8 on my desktop.
The 3.8 programs (including idle.exe pip etc) were installed into the default folder C:\Users{..}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
The 3.9 (without  idle.exe pip etc) was installed on C:\Program Files\Python39

What has changed, and why?

Comment: You should update your system PATH.

Comment: "Windows file association only works with .exe files, not .bat files ..." -- I don't think that is true. See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28189137/4996248) question (although one could quibble that the actual association is to `cmd.exe` with an appropriate argument rather than the bat file per se).

Answer (score 0):

Anything installed in `C:\Users\Someuser\AppData` is installed for Someuser only.  Anything installed in `...\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` comes from Microsoft.  So I presume your 3.8 comes from the Microsoft store.  I believe it will be upgraded to 3.8.6 soon if not yet.  3.8 installed for one user with the python.org installer will, I believe, go by default in the location indicated by `superb rain`.

Your 3.9 is installed for all users with, I presume, the 64-bit installer from Python.org.  The Windows installer predates the Microsoft store version by maybe 2 decades and does not do exactly the same thing.

EDIT: If you can use arguments in a file association, and if 3.9 is indeed from python.org and if you checked the box to install py.exe, then `py -3.9 -m idlelib` should work if Windows simply appends the file path to the string given.

Comment: It is `idle.bat`, not `idle.exe`, your answer does not answer the question

Comment: @KetZoomer The relevant change between the 3.8 and 3.9 installs is the presence or absence of idle.exe, which is not part of Lib/idlelib.  I presume both installs have Lib/idlelib/idle.bat.  I believe the 'why' is because two different installers were used, from different sources, with slightly different ideas about how Python should be installed.